# Create new project: having other packages also installed by default

Tags: symfony

Im creating new projects using `symfony new project_name`. For each project I create, I have always to add the FOSUserBundle package and install it..

Any way to add `FOSUserBundle` automatically when I create a new project using `symfony new project`? Or maybe should I stop using `symfony new project_name` in order to get what I want, that is a different starting point for new projects ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a default composer.json file where these default bundles (that you need) are in. So when you do a composer install it will install these bundles for every project you start.

I always use the current composer.json file for my projects:

https://reformatcode.com/browse